# YAML in ruby 1.8.7 is dropping characters on load

Tags: ruby, encoding, yaml

I have a ruby script that uses YAML to serialize an array of strings and then deserialize them like so:

```
@cache[url_key] = YAML.dump(website_data)

output_array = YAML.load(@cache[url_key])
```

The returned array has a few characters missing, I think line feed characters as shown by wc

```
231     423    6340 website_data
230     423    6241 output_array
```

My reading of stackoverflow indicates that this may be an encoding problem.  I.E. that the YAML.dump encoding is different from the YAML.load encoding, but all the solutions on stackoverflow that I have seen involve rails, and this is just a ruby script with no rails.

---

**Edit 1 -** I tried adding the encoding to the second line of the file but that didn't work.  The first two lines of the ruby script look like

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# encoding: ascii-8bit
```

---

Does anyone know how to set the encoding type for YAML in ruby?

Comment: Did you compare the two data with a comparison tool? (e.g. kdiff). Maybe it's not an encoding problem, but different line ends (CR instead CR+LF)

Comment: I do see ^M at the end of lines on the input but not on the output.  I tried kdiff, and it just said the difference is white space.  kdiff doesn't even point out the ^M differences.  Does kdiff have a setting where it shows the control character differences too?

Comment: If it is different line endings is there a way I can stop the line endings from being changed?

Comment: I think I can't really help. I switched to ruby 1.9 - especially when you work with different encodings it is very helpful.

Comment: Probably just a trailing newline.